# Glib::ustring and Japanese characters

Tags: c++, string, glib

Glib::ustring is supposed to work well with UTF8 but I have a problem when working with Japanese strings.

If you compare those two strings, "わたし" and "ワタシ", using == operator or compare method, it will answer that those two strings are equals.

I don't understand why. How Glib::ustring works ?

The only way I found to get false to the comparison is to compare strings of different sizes. For example "海外わたわ" and "海外わた".

Very strange...

Comment: Kensou did not mention that the two strings he is comparing are different ways of writing out the same sounds, Hiragana and Katakana.  Katakana is used for foreign or "borrowed" words while Hiragana is used for grammar, pronunciation guides for native Japanese words, etc.   In the situation where he is getting false, he is comparing different strings (i.e. "Hell" vs "Hello")

Comment: This seems like a weird "feature", because it would mean that an array of mixed katakana and hiragana strings would sort with no predictable order, and that duplicates would be ordered randomly based on the initial state order of the array.

Answer (score 1):

`Glib::ustring::compare` uses [`g_utf8_collate()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-collate) internally, which compares strings according to the rules of the current locale. Is your locale set to something other than Japanese?

Comment: You might be right, but as long as I'm using an UTF-8 locale (no matter if Japanese or Italian), I should be able to handle UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Lexical comparison is different. It's most likely optimized so that in Latin-alphabet locales, non-Latin characters are all sorted the same and therefore compare the same. It seems a little strange, but if you want to bypass it, get the `c_str` and use `strcmp()` to compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glibmm/ustring.h>
int main() {
  Glib::ustring s1 = "わたし";
  Glib::ustring s2 = "ワタシ";
  std::cerr << (s1 == s2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output: 0

EDIT: But I digged a little deeper:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glibmm.h>
int main() {
  Glib::ustring s1 = "わたし";
  Glib::ustring s2 = "ワタシ";
  std::cout << (s1 == s1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << (s1 == s2) << std::endl;
  std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
  std::cout << (s1 == s1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << (s1 == s2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
1
わたし
ワタシ
```

And this sounds strange.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Locales.html, which says that the standard locale is "C", and that "" maps to your system locale.  I would bet that these days, "" maps to Unicode.  See http://unicode.org/faq/collation.html for more information.