# g_utf8_collate() returns 0 for two Japanese strings which are not equal

Tags: c, utf-8, glib, strcmp

The environment on Linux SLES 15SP2:

```
$ egrep 'LANG|LC_' catserver.log_SRP-30932.20220209
export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
export DB_LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

result of comparing two Japanese strings p1 and p2 with `g_utf8_collate()` and with `strcmp()` and the hex representation of the two strings:

```
p1: [ゲルハルト・A・リッター] p2: [ゲアハルト・A・リッター] g_utf8_collate(): 0 strcmp(): 1
p1: e382b2e383abe3838fe383abe38388e383bb41e383bbe383aae38383e382bfe383bc
p2: e382b2e382a2e3838fe383abe38388e383bb41e383bbe383aae38383e382bfe383bc
...
p1: [チャールズ・A・ビアード] p2: [ゲルハルト・A・リッター] g_utf8_collate(): 0 strcmp(): 1
p1: e38381e383a3e383bce383abe382bae383bb41e383bbe38393e382a2e383bce38389
p2: e382b2e383abe3838fe383abe38388e383bb41e383bbe383aae38383e382bfe383bc
```

I don't know what these Japanese strings mean. They're from a bibliographic database where our Library Management System is failing due to the above problem with `g_utf8_collate()` and I've inserted the `strcmp()` and the hex dump in the tons of C-code to understand the failure.

Comment: (`g_utf8_collate()` is like `strcoll()`, not `strcmp()`, btw. Two strings with different codepoints can still be equivalent according to the rules they use.)

Comment: Does this say "only the first pair of strings"?

Answer (score 1):

## Background

1. Look at the pair: only one character is different:

   - ゲ**ル**ハルト・A・リッター = Ge**ru**haruto A rittā
   - ゲ**ア**ハルト・A・リッター = ge**a**haruto A rittā

   These are two ways to write the name [Gerhard A. Ritter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_A._Ritter) in [Katakanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana). Japanese speakers do that for the same reason why English speakers would create the name [*Maria Sharapova*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Sharapova) although the real name is [Мари́я Шара́пова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) - it is the closest way to write that name in a different system. And sometimes there is not only one way to do so.

   In this case both ways to write "Gerhard" can be considered *same*. However, I cannot imagine a collation that exists which interpretes two entirely different Kanas as *same* - this cannot be correct.
2. Now the other pair, which has nothing in common besides the latin `A`:

   - チャールズ・A・ビアード = chāruzu A biādo = [Charles A. Beard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_A._Beard)
   - ゲルハルト・A・リッター = geruharuto A rittā (same as first p1)

   [Charles also has a japanese article in Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA%E3%83%BB%E3%83%93%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89), so you can see his name exactly written like here. These are two different persons and everything besides `・A・` mismatches - in no way can any collation see these as *same* - there must be a bigger mistake that happens.

Library wise you just have to expect different writing systems for the same name, especially when wanting to look things up/find them (again), since there's no rule whose name must be written in which writing system. Examples:

| Latin letters | Katakana (japanese) | Hebrew | Cyrillic (russian) | Arabic | Greek |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Ken Ishii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Ishii) | [ケン・イシイ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A4) | [קן_אישיי](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%99) | Кен Исии | [كين إيشي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%83%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A5%D9%8A%D8%B4%D9%8A) | Κεν Ίσιι |
| [Michael Schumacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Schumacher) | [ミハエル・シューマッハ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%8F) | [מיכאל שומאכר](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%A8) | [Михаэ́ль Шума́хер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%80,_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8D%D0%BB%D1%8C) | [مايكل شوماخر](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%83%D9%84_%D8%B4%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%B1) | [Μίχαελ Σουμάχερ](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C%CE%AF%CF%87%CE%B1%CE%B5%CE%BB_%CE%A3%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%AC%CF%87%CE%B5%CF%81) |

## Solution

*glib* wise there's

- a [Red Hat ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1712634) describing similar impossible results, and
- the question [Glib::ustring and Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2469086/4299358) along with answers.

Both point out: you cannot have a locale of `de_DE.UTF-8` and then collation wise compare non-German input. If you want to use `g_utf8_collate()` on Katakanas you have to set your locale to e.g. `ja_JP.UTF-8`.

Your new problem may become: recognize the writing system from the characters and set the locale accordingly. However, this already easily clashes with latin letters being used in many alphabets (English, German, Turkish...).

Comment: The server in question was updated from `SLES 15SP2` to `SP3`, and compare of the above strings give now `rc=42` for the first string pair and `rc=8` for the second. With the locale `de_DE.UTF-8`.

Comment: You may want to look up your [glib version(s)](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/) and their [changelog](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/releases)s, because that is what you use, not SLES directly.